# Calculating difference of Buy and SELL Qty in a pandas DataFrame Rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

There is a Item wise difference in Buy and Sell required for my data below

**My current DF looks like this**:

```
    Items  Type   Qty 
0   myitem1   BUY  1546 
1   myitem1  SELL  1340 
2   myitem2  BUY   149 
3   myitem2  SELL   130 
4   myitem4   SELL   100 
5   newitem   BUY  1000 
6   newitem  SELL  1000
```

I wish the desired output to be the difference of Buy, Sell. i.e.

```
    Items  Type   Qty 
   myitem1   BUY  206 
   myitem2  BUY   19 
   myitem4   SELL   100
```

**Note**:The Rows above may have only one of `Buy` Or `Sell` for certain items In this case for it is for Item4

Further the output does not have to contain equal Items, (in this case  newitem is the example)

I have tried various ways to achieve this using DF groupby etc. however I am unable to get the above Output.

Comment: I had checked the posted link, Unfortunately this doesn't solve my exact query.. In my case there is a difference between Buy and sell.. And In some cases One of them (i.e. Buy OR Sell) row may not be present for an Item.

Comment: Try iterating over df by items and then do df.loc['Buy']-df.loc['Sell']. Put additional check if there is any value for df.loc['Buy'] or sell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np

df.groupby(['Items']).apply(lambda x: 
                                      np.select([x['Type'] == 'SELL', x['Type'] == 'BUY'], [x['Qty']*-1, x['Qty']])
                                     ).apply(sum).rename('Qty').to_frame().assign(
        Type = lambda x: np.select([x['Qty'] <0, x['Qty']>0, x['Qty']==0], ['SELL', 'BUY', None]),
        Qty = lambda x: x['Qty'].abs()
    ).dropna()
```

Output:

```
         Qty    Type
Items       
myitem1  206    BUY
myitem2  19     BUY
myitem4  100    SELL
```

Comment: this Works, Thank Gyx-hh.. I have tested with various forms of Data, this worked in every case. Thx again.

Comment: Looks very complicated. Can you post easier version please?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
df_out = (df.assign(Qty = np.where(df.Type == 'SELL', -df.Qty, df.Qty))
            .groupby('Items')['Qty'].sum().reset_index())
df_out['TYPE'] = np.where(np.sign(df_out.Qty)==1,'BUY','SELL')
df_out.assign(Qty=df_out.Qty.abs()).query('Qty > 0')
```

Output:

```
     Items  Qty  TYPE
0  myitem1  206   BUY
1  myitem2   19   BUY
2  myitem4  100  SELL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try of grouping by Items and  getting absolute value of difference

```
 df.set_index(['Items']).groupby(df.set_index(['Items']).index)['Qty'].diff().abs().dropna()
```

Out:

```
Items
myitem1    206.0
myitem2     19.0
newitem      0.0
```

Comment: Naga, all is fine except for the myitem4 Does NOT appear in output, Would you suggest me to change the original DF and put in a Sell Row just to get the Output ?

Comment: I do appreciate your effort, Naga.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work

Just add more conditions in if & else acc. to your data 
   import pandas as pd

```
data = [['myitem1',10,'Sell'],['myitem1',12,'Buy'],['myitem2',13,'Buy']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Items','Qty','Type'])
mylist =[]
for (idx,row) in df.iterrows():
    a = df.loc[df['Items'] == row.Items]
    item_name =a.Items
    a = a.sort_values('Type')
    no_types=a['Type'].nunique()
    if no_types ==2:
        Final_Qty = a.loc[[0],'Qty'] - a.loc[[1],'Qty']
        if Final_Qty > 0:
            new_type = "Buy"
        else:
            new_type = "Sell"
    elif no_types ==1:
        ## Code if there is only buy or sell
    mylist.append=([item_name,new_type,Final_Qty])
```

Comment: Rahul, I am unable to test this, Anyways this appears to be a Long code compared to the available alternatives.

Comment: Yes this is a longer version,but more readable. You can go with another solution but if you want something readable let me know..I can update my answer which will give desired output